# How to initialize a field in a widget's state with the value returned by an async method?

Tags: flutter

I have a Data Accessor Object with async functions.

I can't write:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final itemDao = ItemDao();
  List<Item> _list = await itemDao.getAllItems();
...
}
```

Because that's an illegal use of `await`, and I can't make the class definition async.

So how do I initialize this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an async method that retrieves the data then calls `setState`. Then call this method in `initState`.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _itemDao = ItemDao();
  List<Item> _list = [];
  Future _setList() async {
    _list = await _itemDao.getAllItems();
    setState(() {});
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setList();
  }
  ...
}
```